# How do I use PurgeCSS with Next.js and module.scss files?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, next.js, css-purge

I've got component level .scss files (filename.module.scss)
and I want to purge unused css from these files.

Since the styling classnames get hashed. I was wondering how I can get purgeCSS to work with a next.js app that uses module.scss files for most of the styling.

https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/163#issuecomment-526607181
this issue here goes over it but for a react application

Comment: Have you tried what's in the official documentation: https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html#next-js? What does your PostCSS config file look like?

Comment: @juliomalves I did but the issue was that my styling from my modules was removed. 

I have fileName.module.scss for every component / page file and they went poof.

Comment: A few of my packages that require extra css seem to also have all their CSS just removed.

Comment: Edit: Seems like its working now (modules) using the config from that link you sent me - but some library styles are missing (react-multi-carousel has import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css"; imported in _app.js)

Comment: I tried adding their class names to the whitelist in postcss.config.js 
```
        safelist: ["html", "body", /^react-/, /^navbar-/]
```

but this didn't do anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a dedicated NPM package [next-purge-css-modules](https://github.com/eels/next-purge-css-modules), made just for this purpose:

```
npm install next-purge-css-modules
```

and in your `next.config.js`, use:

```
const withPurgeCSSModules = require('next-purge-css-modules');
const nextConfig = { ... };

module.exports = withPurgeCSSModules(nextConfig);
```

Comment: `withPurgeCSSModules` is not in the list of allowed properties for `nextConfig`. Also the package is outdated.